# Connecting to MySQL from NodeJS (Express App) throws error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

edit:
Solved my problem. After removing the line

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

I got the raw MySQL error message saying that the login credentials for MySQL are wrong. I already checked my passwort, but din't noticed the wrong username. Very sorry fr my dumb question.

---

I have a NodeJS / Express app. It was already working fine but know I dont'get a connection any more to MySQL (MariaDB). Always I try to start the app (with pm2) the start failed, because a exception is thrown.

I have already checked if MySQL is running and I also restarted MySQL and NodeJS app and pdated node-mysql. This is my code for connecting to mysql:

```
//local mysql db connection
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'xxx',
    database : 'lizenzverwaltung'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

module.exports = connection;
```

The error message on startup is:

```
0|www      |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
0|www      |     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
0|www      |     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
0|www      |     --------------------
0|www      |     at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
0|www      |     at Protocol.handshake (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
0|www      |     at Connection.connect (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
0|www      |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/models/db.js:11:12)
0|www      |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
0|www      |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
0|www      |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
0|www      |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
0|www      |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
0|www      |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
```

If I comment out the line
`if (err) throw err;`
I can start the NodeJS app, but get the following error, as soon, as I try to run a SQL query:

```
0|www      |     at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:212:16)
0|www      |     at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:138:13)
0|www      |     at Connection.query (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:201:25)
0|www      |     at Function.verifyLicense [as verify] (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/models/licenseModel.js:29:9)
0|www      |     at Function.LicenseController.veryLicense (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/controllers/licenseController.js:51:18)
0|www      |     at /var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/routes/license.js:33:21
0|www      |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
0|www      |     at next (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
0|www      |     at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
0|www      |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR', fatal: false }
0|www      | error { Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.
0|www      |     at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:212:16)
0|www      |     at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:138:13)
0|www      |     at Connection.query (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:201:25)
0|www      |     at Function.verifyLicense [as verify] (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/models/licenseModel.js:29:9)
0|www      |     at Function.LicenseController.veryLicense (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/controllers/licenseController.js:51:18)
0|www      |     at /var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/routes/license.js:33:21
0|www      |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
0|www      |     at next (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
0|www      |     at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
0|www      |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/lizenzverwaltung/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR', fatal: false } result null
0|www      | POST /v1/license/verify/ 200 19.128 ms - 16
```

I already searched but didn't found a solution. Do you have any tips? My MySQL server should working fine, PHPMyAdmin and my Wordpress sites are running fine.

Thanks,
Klaus

Comment: Is the mysql server designated to listen from other adresses?

Comment: Place your edited text saying that it is resolved at the top of everything, please, so that users do not read all your problem until we get to the end and see that it is already resolved.

Comment: Or write an answer and mark it as valid so that it appears as resolved in the list of questions

Comment: thanks, I will do
edit: hmm, I have to wait for 2 days before I can accept my answer. Have moved my edit to the top now

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. After removing the line

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

I got the raw MySQL error message saying that the login credentials for MySQL are wrong. I already checked my passwort, but din't noticed the wrong username. Very sorry for my dumb question.